# AVPlayer can't play from document

Tags: ios, objective-c

My issue is the following when I get the file from the bundle I don't have any issue to play it with the AVPlayer.
But when I use the file sharing with iTunes and I try to play the file from the document folder and it doesn't work.

.h

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController *videoController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;
```

.m

The url get is the following (already try with mov , mp4 and mpg) : `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D35C60F9-6656-421C-8798-FB938321C86E/Documents/foo.mpg`

```
    - (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {

    if(videoArray && [videoArray count] >= 1){

        if(!self.videoController){
            self.videoController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
        }

        // create an AVPlayer
        NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoArray[0]];
        //self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:videoURL];
        self.player  = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

        self.videoController.player = self.player;
        [self.videoController.player play];

        //listen for end
        //[self.videoController.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:0];

        // show the view controller
        self.videoController.showsPlaybackControls = false;
        self.videoController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
        [self addChildViewController:self.videoController];
        [self.view addSubview:self.videoController.view];

    }
}
```

Comment: @PhillipMills the variables contains some adresses after initialization so I supposed they are well assigned.

Comment: i think the problm is the mpg format ,,... i just replace mp4 videos it works for me friend...